# How can I stack up the number patterns with while loop in java?

Tags: java, while-loop, nested-loops

Dear Professionals!
I'm a super beginner of programming java. 
I'm just learning a basic stuff in school.
While I'm doing my homework, I'm stuck in one problem.

The question is Using nested loops to make this stack-up number pattern:

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I can only use while loop (because we haven't learned for or do loops yet), and the outer loop body should execute 10 times. 
I can use print and println for making this pattern.

I tried many different methods with while loop, but I can't figure it out.

Please, please give me some hint.

This is the code that I'm working on it so far:

```
class C4h8
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i, j;

        i = 1;
        while(i <= 10)
        {
            j = 1;
            while (j <= 10)
            {

                System.out.print(j);
                j++;

            }


            System.out.println();
            i++;

        }

    }
}
```

but it only displays:

```
12345678910
12345678910
12345678910
12345678910
12345678910
12345678910
12345678910
12345678910
12345678910
12345678910
```

My question may look like a silly one, but I'm really struggling with it because like I mentioned, I'm a super beginner..
Please help me, so that I can learn and move on!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Use while(j<=i) in the inner while loop. It will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following: You need to limit the variable `j` by variable `i` to achieve your output

```
class C4h8
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i, j;

        i = 1;
        while(i <= 10)
        {
            j = 1;
            while (j <= i) // limit the variable j by i 
            {

                System.out.print(j+" ");
                j++;

            }

            System.out.println();
            i++;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

In less code with while loop

```
int i = 0;
int limit = 10;
while(++i <= limit){
    int j = 0;
    while(++j <= i)
        System.out.print(j+" ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely try this! :)

Comment: @learnerh Don't until you learn what it means, and understand that more readable code is better than fancier code any day.

Comment: You are welcome! I think You should mark this question as answered, don't you? :)